# Animation style of MPMoviePlayerViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, stream, uiviewanimation, movie

My question is simple and clear: I want to learn what animation transition style of MPMoviePlayerViewController has since I want to use same animation transition style when I want to open a picture rather than movie.

Note: I already searched around the classes, but haven't found any answers yet.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

`MPMoviePlayerViewController` inhirets from `UIViewController` and hence you have `modalTransitionStyle` property. have you tried it?

Comment: I did but it did not help. What I want is, when I click on image, it is going to open just like an ordinary video opening -I mean its transition style- and when I click on done, it is going to come back just like an ordinary video closing.

Comment: Well, having the transition style of the `videoPlayerController` you can create a `viewController` and put the image in it to fill the view, change presentation style via setting `modalTransitionStyle` value to be he same as `videoPlayerController` and then present it using `presentViewController:animated:completion:`